# PyCharm can't open file from Docker container: No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pycharm

I have a docker-compose.yml file that creates a Python image (named "flask") and a Postgres image (named "database"). When I attempt to run any of my Python scripts/files, I get the following message from my Python image:

`flask       | python: can't open file '/home/username/Projects/ProjectName/app/src/script.py": [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

If anyone could provide some insight or steps to resolve this issue, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
        app:
                container_name: flask
                build:
                        context: ./app
                ports:
                        - 8000:8000
                depends_on:
                        - database
        database:
                container_name: postgres
                build:
                        context: ./postgres
                ports:
                        - 5432:5432
```

app/dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
COPY . .
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:8000", "--access-logfile", "-", "--error-logfile", "-", "--log-level", "debug",  "wsgi"]
```

postgres/dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:latest

COPY database_object_creation /init-queries/

ENV POSTGRES_USER=username
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
ENV PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD
ENV POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
ENV POSTGRES_PORT=5432
ENV POSTGRES_DB=databasename

COPY dbinit.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Run/Debug Configurations in PyCharm:
(some fields intentionally left blank)

```
Script path: /home/username/Projects/ProjectName/app/src/script.py
Parameters:
Environment variables: PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
Interpreter options:
Working directory: /home/username/Projects/ProjectName/app/src
Path mappings:
Add content roots to PYTHONPATH: (checked)
Add source roots to PYTHONPATH: (checked)
Run with Python Console: (unchecked)
Redirect input from:
Command and options:
Command preview:
Before launch Activate tool window:
```

Project Remote Python Interpreter:
(some fields intentionally left blank)

```
Name: Remote Python 3.8.1 Docker Compose (app at [/home/username/Projects/ProjectName/./docker-compose.yml])
Docker Compose (checked)
Server: Docker
Configuration file(s): ./docker-compose.yml
Service: app
Environment variables:
Python interpreter path: python
Execute code using this interpreter with root privileges via sudo (unchecked)
PyCharm helpers path: /opt/.pycharm_helpers
```

I've also noticed that PyCharm is creating (and maybe using?) this yml file.
/home/username/.PyCharm2019.3/system/tmp/docker-compose.override.10.yml

```
version "3.7"
services:
  app:
    command:
    - "python"
    - "-u"
    - "/home/username/Projects/ProjectName/app/src/script.py"
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: "/home/username/Projects/ProjectName:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend:/opt/.pycharm_helpers/pycharm_display"
      PYTHONUNBUFFERED: "1"
      PYTHONIOENCODING: "UTF-8"
      PYCHARM_HOSTED: "1"
      PYCHARM_DISPLAY_PORT: "63342"
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
    - "/home/username/Projects/ProjectName/.:/opt/project:rw"
    - "pycharm_helpers_PY-193.5662.61:/opt/.pycharm_helpers"
    working_dir: "/home/username/Projects/ProjectName/app/src"
volumes:
  pycharm_helpers_PY-193.5662.61: {}
```

Comment: Where is flask getting that path from? That won't be a valid path in your container, since you copy everything into `/app`

Comment: maybe he need to add a `ADD . /app` before `WORKDIR` in Dockerfile?

Comment: Also, how are you running the container?

Comment: @Oysiyl the `COPY . .` at the end, after setting the `WORKDIR` earlier, should do the job fine.  (But it'll be in `/app` and not the user's home directory on the build system.)

Comment: I work with him, his code runs fine with `docker-compose up`. He only gets this path issue when running specific files from PyCharm. Some how, pycharm is passing this local path to the docker container. He's running in PyCharm with the app image as the project's interpreter.

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting So OP is using PyCharm to run the containers?

Comment: @C.Nivs I've added my PyCharm run configuration to the question. Please let me know if you need any additional information. Thanks.

Comment: @C.Nivs Correct. In PyCharm, where you add interpreters to select from, he has gone the docker compose route. He had this all working fine. This randomly begins to happen to him after some time of it working.

Comment: Ok, so when you run code in PyCharm, behind the scenes it will pass in the script argument as the full path, and it will change the working directory. However, to get that to work in a container, you'd need to mount your entire home directory as a volume (which obviously is a no-starter). I'd stick with the docker compose route if you need compose. If you want to run scripts through that IDE, you should not select a container's runtime. Part of the reason for this is that the runtime is ephemeral and will only exist as long as the container does. [1]

Comment: That is, when you tear down everything, you will have to re-point PyCharm to the *new* container and its interpreter, which introduces a lot of complexity and fragility

Comment: If it's already running in docker-compose, why try to use pycharm to run the code there?

Comment: @C.Nivs Debugging, unit testing

Comment: @JoshuaSchlichting while I understand the desire to keep debugging tools that are probably used in the day-to-day workflow, once your code is running in a container, it's best to treat it like it's in a remote server. If you are still doing basic debugging, use PyCharm to run the code locally (not in a container) and test from there. After that, run the container and monitor logs while interacting with the service. If you are having to run the files using PyCharm, your image setup is not *quite* done

Comment: @C.Nivs The point of PyCharm's integration with docker is for development. We're not looking to "keep debugging tools" around once we deploy. This is purely development going on right now. His issues are happening when debugging/unit testing from PyCharm with docker. He has 0 issues when he runs this stuff with `docker-compose up`, just, he can't use the awesome features of PyCharm when running things this way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205153/discussion-between-c-nivs-and-joshua-schlichting).